# Maximise $f(x) = 4x + \int_0^1 [(12x + 20y)xy f(y)] \,dy$

Tags: calculus, optimization

in this question I am given a function

$$f(x) = 4x + \int_0^1 [(12x + 20y)xy f(y)]  \,dy= 0$$

And question asks to find the maximum value of $$8f(x)$$

My approach: I tried applying [Leibniz Integral Rule](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/LeibnizIntegralRule.html) but the limits of the integral are definite that is 0 and 1. Also there are two variables inside the integration(x and y). But I think that can be sorted out by taking x as a constant since we are integrating y. So I also tried simplifying the integral before solving it but was not able to solve it. For $$f(x)$$ to be maximum $$f'(x) = 0$$ So that was my approach. I'd like to know where I am going wrong and also if there would be a way to somehow graph this function. I've being trying it for quite a while. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

(I am a 12th grade student)

Comment: Please try to make the titles of your questions more informative. For example, *Why does $a<b$ imply $a+c<b+c$?* is much more useful for other users than *A question about inequality.* From [How can I ask a good question?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/589/): *Make your title as descriptive as possible. In many cases one can actually phrase the title as the question, at least in such a way so as to be comprehensible to an expert reader.* You can find more tips for choosing a good title [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/10144/).

Comment: @Shaun Got it! I'll definitely incorporate your advice in the next question I post on this site.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I like this question a lot!

Your intuition is good; we want to know where $f'(x)=0$, but the issue is that we can't evaluate the integral of $f$, since this depends on $f$ itself. In particular, if we define the two constants

$$C=\int_0^1yf(y)dy,\;\;\;\;D=\int_0^1y^2f(y)dy$$

then our equation reads

$$f(x)=4x+12x^2C+20xD$$

If we multiply this equation by $x$ and integrate from $0$ to $1$, then the left side becomes $C$, so we have

$$C=\frac{4}{3}+3C+\frac{20}{3}D$$

Similarly, we could multiply by $x^2$ and integrate to get $D$ on the left, so we have

$$D=1+\frac{12}{5}C+5D$$

Now we have two equations with two unknowns, $C$ and $D$, so we can solve for these values. Once you know $C$ and $D$, you know $f$, so you are good to proceed with your original thought.

Comment: I like your answer possibly as much as you like the question

Answer (score -1):

Yes, this is the same as $f(x)= 4x+ 12x^2\int_0^1 yf(y)dy+ 20x\int_0^1 y^2f(y)dy$ and the integrals are constants with respect to x.

$f'(x)= 4+ 24x\int_0^1 yf(y)dy+ 20\int_0^1 y^2f(y)dy= 0$
$24x\int_0^1 yf(y)dy= -4- 20\int_0^1 y^2f(y)dy$

$x= \frac{-4- 20\int_0^1 y^2f(y)dy}{\int_0^1 yf(y)dy}$

Now the problem is evaluating those integrals!

Comment: how do we solve these integrals since we don't know what f(y) is? So do they have to cancel out or something?